# How does c compiler interpret declaring function and variable in the same statement?

Tags: c, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

I came across one of the declaration in K&R, where a function and a variable are declared together in the 'Pointers' chapter:

```
double atof(), *dp;
```

How does a C compiler handle above declaration?

Comment: With ease. What's the actual problem here?

Comment: You are obviously already clear that it will declare a functiona and a variable. So what is your question? What gives you doubts about this? Is there another outcome you are considering?

Comment: i'm clear with atof, but how is *dp evaluated to, because if double specifies the return type of atof, doesn't it end the statement there?? and we need to declare *dp on a new line??

Comment: The comma separates the things being declared. If the compiler sees a comma ending the thing being declared, it looks for another. If it sees a semicolon, it knows the statement has ended.

Comment: Just don't read K&R, it is extremely outdated and teaching you bad practice. There is never a reason why you would write some crap code like that. And the correct type for atof would be `double atof (const char* str);`, declared as a prototype at file scope.

Comment: Are you actually just wondering what type `dp` is in this case ? (it would be the same as if you just wrote `double *dp;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for declarations (C17 6.7) is:

```
declaration:
  declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list(opt) ;
```

where one case of *declaration-specifiers* is *type-specifier*, in this case `double`.

Digging further into the *init-declarator-list* gives *init-declarator*, optionally several separated by comma:

```
init-declarator-list:
  init-declarator
  init-declarator-list , init-declarator
```

*init_declarator* in turn gives *declarator*, which has the syntax (C17 6.7.6):

```
declarator:
  pointer(opt) direct-declarator
```

In the example, `atof()` and `dp` are *direct-declarator*, where `dp` has the optional pointer syntax.

This means that `atof()` ends up a function returning `double` and `*dp` a pointer to `double`.

(If you want to dig through the raw syntax like above, Annex A of the standard is helpful. No sane person remembers things like this without looking them up.)

---

But there is really no reason to ponder awfully written code like this. The following is widely recognized as bad practice:

- Writing function declarations anywhere else but as a line of its own, at file scope.
- Writing function declarations that do not have prototype format. The correct prototype for `atof` in standard C 7.22.1.1 is `double atof(const char *nptr);`. Whereas `double atof()` means a function taking any parameter. This is obsolete style as per C17 6.11.6.
- Writing multiple declarations at a single line. Don't write things like `double d, *dp;`, write `double d; double* dp;`. The former is known to cause bugs because of accidentally declaring the wrong type. As a bonus, if you always split the declarations, you don't have to ponder if it is more correct to write `double* dp` style or `double *dp` style.

Summary: don't read obsolete programming books from the 1970s. The attempted K&R update to C90 was sloppily made and a lot of the 2nd edition of the book is not up to date with 1989 years changes. For example the obsolete style was already there in C90 6.9.4. So the book contains practice that was already flagged obsolete by the C standard in the year 1989! Plain horrible.

Answer (score 1):

In C, comma can function as an operator or a separator. In your case, it functions as a separator.

If you go through the C grammar available online [here](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html), you will find many uses of comma as separator.
One of the uses is below:

```
init_declarator_list
    : init_declarator
    | init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator
```